# Let $F:L^3[0,2]\to \mathbb R$ defined as $F\left(f\right)=\int _0^2t^{-\frac{2}{5}}f\left(t\right)dt.$ Find $||F||$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Find $||F||$. Let $F:L^3[0,2]\to \mathbb R$ defined as
$$F\left(f\right)=\int _0^2t^{-\frac{2}{5}}f\left(t\right)dt.$$

**My attempt:-**

$|T(f)|=|\int _0^2t^{-\frac{2}{5}}f(t)dt|\leq\int_0^1|t^{\frac{2}{5}}f(t)|dt\leq (\int_0^2 (t^{-\frac{2}{5}})^{\frac{3}{2}}dt)^{\frac{2}{3}}(\int_0^2 |f(t)|^3dt)^{\frac{1}{3}}(\because$ by Holder, inequality)
$\leq (\int_0^2 |f(t)|^3dt)^{\frac{1}{3}}=||f||_3\implies ||F||\leq 1.$

> Let $f(t)=\frac{1}{2} t^{2/5}\in L^3[0,2].$ I am getting
> $F(f)=1\implies ||F||=1.$ (Attempt was wrong)

Sorry. It was mistaken. $f$ is not in the closed unit ball. I am not able to find the function which gives $T(f)=1.$

Comment: What happens for $f(t)=c\cdot t^{-\frac{1}{5}}$?

Comment: Also, your integral after applying Holder is not $1$, but greater, so did you mean to say you have proved $||F||\leq C$ for that some $C=(\int_0^2t^{-\frac{3}{5}})^\frac{2}{3}$ ?

Comment: When $c=2^{3/5}/5$, I get $T(f)=1$

Comment: Good, then it should hold for all $c$ since the norm scales linearly.

Comment: Also $||f||_3\leq 1$. I hope that $||F||=1$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, by definition, $||F||=\sup_f\frac{T(f)}{||f||_3}$, so if you proved it to be $\leq1$ and found a function for which it is $1$, then $||F||=1$.

Comment: But you haven't proven it to be $\leq1$, but $\leq2.22$ (approx.)

Comment: Yes. It is $\leq 2.2159910633.$

Comment: It looks to me like that value is the $||F||$ and that for $f=c\cdot t^{-\frac{1}{5}}$ it is actually that value and not $1$. Can you check?

Comment: I got $T(f)=5c/(2^{3/5})$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*First estimate:*

Using the Hölder's inequality $(*)$, we have with the respective dual exponent,
$$|Ff|=\left|\int_{0}^{2}t^{-2/5}f(t)\, dt \right|\underbrace{\leqslant}_{(*)} \|t^{-2/5}\|_{L^{3/2}}\cdot \|f\|_{L^{3}} $$
Setting $c:=\|t^{-2/5}\|_{L^{3/2}}$ and since $\|F\|:=\sup\{|Ff|:\|f\|_{L^{3}}=1\}$ and we have $|Ff|\leqslant c\|f\|_{L^{3}}$, hence $\boxed{\|F\|\leqslant c} $.

*Second estimate:*

By reverse engineer, let $f(t)=at^{-1/5}$, with $a:=5^{-1/3}\cdot2^{1/5}$, then notice that $f$ works since $\|f\|_{L^{3}}=1$. Then, we can see that

$$\|F\|\geqslant |Ff|=\left|\int_{0}^{2}\underbrace{t^{-2/5}f(t)}_{\geqslant 0; t\in [0,2]}\,dt\right|=a\int_{0}^{2}t^{-3/5}\, dt=c.$$
Thus $\boxed{\|F\|\geqslant c}$.

Therefore, $\boxed{\|F\|=c}$.